# All FHIR JSON schema do not validate

Tags: json, jsonschema, hl7, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to use the JSON schema defined at www.hl7.org/fhir/json.html, such as www.hl7.org/fhir/Patient.schema.json.

The schema begins with:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://hl7.org/fhir/json-schema/Patient",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/Patient",
  "description": "see http://hl7.org/fhir/json.html#schema for information 
  about the FHIR Json Schemas",
  "definitions": {
  "Patient": {
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "DomainResource#/definitions/DomainResource"
    },
```

When I paste this into [www.jsonschemavalidator.net][3], I get the error

> Error when resolving schema reference '#/definitions/Patient'. Path '', line 1, position 1.

If I move line 4 ("$ref": "#/definitions/Patient") inside the "Patient" definition, the schema parsing error is fixed, and I can correctly validate some sample JSON data.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://hl7.org/fhir/json-schema/Patient",
  "description": "see http://hl7.org/fhir/json.html#schema for information 
  about the FHIR Json Schemas",
  "definitions": {
  "Patient": {

  "$ref": "#/definitions/Patient",

  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "DomainResource#/definitions/DomainResource"
    },
```

However, I notice that every JSON schema defined at http://hl7.org/fhir/json.html is structured this way. Is the error in the HL7 JSON schemas, or in the way www.jsonschemavalidator.net is parsing these JSON schemas?

My understanding of $ref, is that "$ref": "#/definitions/Patient" looks at the nearest parent id for the baseURL, which in this case is:

"hl7.org/fhir/json-schema/Patient".

This URL should serve www.hl7.org/fhir/Patient.schema.json, which from the root element, should have a schema element #/definitions/Patient which corresponds to the current element in which $ref is defined. So it seems the proper placement of $ref should indeed be inside #/definitions/Patient, not in the upper root #/ location, where the ref is currently located.

Comment: see related conversation here: https://gitter.im/ajv-validator/ajv?at=58f484c208c00c092a8a5787 - not sure it is the same issue though

Comment: I don't read the json schema spec the way you do. I think the schemas are correct. Your 'correction' to the schemas means that any json at all is valid

Comment: I am following up on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/json-schema. Feel free to join there

Answer (score 0):

The schemas are valid.  I recommend a different online validator that handles the `$ref` keyword properly.  https://jsonschemalint.com is my recommendation (even though it uses the term "lint" incorrectly).  It's backed by AJV, so you can be sure it's done correctly.

To be fair to www.jsonschemavalidator.net, this is a very odd use of `$ref`.  It's not technically wrong, but it's unusual.  My recommendation to the author of the schema would be to inline that top level `$ref`.  There will be a wider range of validators that will handle it properly.

Getting back to the online validation problem, even with a good validator, it's not going to work.  If you try the Patient schema with https://jsonschemalint.com, you get the error

> can't resolve reference DomainResource#/definitions/DomainResource from id http://hl7.org/fhir/json-schema/Patient#

The problem is that the Patient schema references a schema in a *different document* that the validator can't or won't fetch.  If you resolve the `$ref` against the `id`, you will get a URI for the schema you need, but I know of no online validators that do that.  According to the JSON Schema specification, this isn't a behavior you can rely on anyway.

The other option is an online validator that allows you to specify more than one schema.  But, I haven't seen one that has that feature.

If online validation is that important, you will probably need to setup something yourself that is specifically for validating against these schemas.  It's fairly easy to do.  Hopefully you will even make it public so others can benefit as well.

Comment: I'm trying to use the jsonschema with AJV for post data validation but I get "Maximum call stack size exceed" error. Probably because of self referencing. There is a solution to fix this? Thanks